# How to add tap and long press gesture to image in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to add long press and tap gesture recognization in xamarin forms. Successfully added long press effect in xamarin forms but long press gesture is working and tap gesture is not working. how to work both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of image use ImageButton it  works